# What are the maximum field lengths on Evenbrite?

Tags: eventbrite

We are exporting Evenbrite data (via the API) to a third party system.  To make the third party system as efficient as possible, it would be useful to know what the maximum field lengths are for the standard Eventbrite fields (e.g. affiliate, amount paid, company, etc).  Is there a list anywhere?  (or are they all 255 characters?).  I've had a look, but haven't found anything to date.

Cheers in advance!